# Keep only specific id Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table Foo

id

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
```

i have a table Bar

```
foo_id = 1 test = 1
foo_id = 2 test = 0
foo_id = 4 test = 1
foo_id = 5 test = 1
```

I want to retrieve id from foo where bar test = 0 or not exist in bar.

I have

```
$id = Foo::with('bar')->whereHas('bar', function ($q)
  {$q->where('test', '=', 0)
  ->orWhereNull(foo_id???????);})
->get();
```

How can i write this down?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right general track, but your `whereHas` can't find anything in `bar` that doesn't exist. Try this approach instead:

```
$id = Foo::with('bar')
    ->whereHas('bar', function ($q) {
        $q->where('test', '=', 0);
    }
    ->orWhereDoesntHave('bar')
    ->get();
```

Now, you're looking for a `Foo` that has a `bar` where `test` is `0`, or that doesn't have a `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = Foo::with('bar')->whereHas('bar', function ($q)
  {
    $q->where('test', '=', 0)
      ->whereNotIn(
          'foo_id', DB::raw("SELECT foo_id FROM bar"), 'or'
      );
  })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly according to your need.

```
$bars = DB::table('foos')
            ->Join('bars', function($join) {
              $join->on('foos.id', '=', 'bars.foo_id')
                  ->where('bars.test', '!=', '0');
            })
            ->select('foos.id');

  $result = DB::table('foos')
              ->leftJoin('bars', 'foos.id', '=', 'bars.foo_id')
              ->select('foos.id')
              ->whereNull('bars.foo_id')
              ->union($bars)
              ->get();
```